# How could be practical to implement Crysis nanosuit style menu in Javascript web-page?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, menu, html

Got an idea for some modern cool looking menus for web pages. How to actually implement them? Did some good javascript libraries already make that easily possible? Reference implementations found? This can already been asked but I just don't know what name has such menu thing. Edit: Now I know. It's circular menu. Any best practices for doing it?

Intuition came from these Crysis nanosuit menus, see images below:

- [Most preferable option](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ExftBi3eFbk/TduRFFcvGNI/AAAAAAAAADs/1sHLFI-DDwc/s1600/nano+suit+module+select.jpg)
- [Good goal for starting](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/TvX8nqGTWH5Oq_9sPHRa33WBohJPKxV8xF9hsg97eImpvm9o3yJ-t1PT5mCew4pF04CT1SZDfTRrahAjqZUGgfDq1R4KuQsAf4Rc6_bOAL4lprojECw)
- [Advanced version](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ExftBi3eFbk/TduRFFcvGNI/AAAAAAAAADs/1sHLFI-DDwc/s1600/nano+suit+module+select.jpg)

Keep sharing ideas!

Comment: Beginner question gets beginner rating. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these sorts of menus have different names like path menu, circle menu or pie menu. here are some links (examples + source code) that contains some examples that can get you started:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/

http://creative-punch.net/2014/02/making-animated-radial-menu-css3-javascript/

i hope this helps

Comment: there is an other code example from an other post:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790341/creating-a-circular-menu-with-css

and a jQuery plugin: http://jquery-plugins.net/circle-menu-customizable-circular-menu-jquery-plugin

Comment: You provided pretty much everything I could imagine to get started. Thank you so much! If you have more sources for such implementations please edit answer or comment them as well.